# java cast error:[Ljava.lang.Byte; incompatible with [B

Tags: java, casting

I have encounterd a starnge java cast error.

when I cast some object to byte[],

```
byte [] a = new byte[lenght];
a = (byte[])obj;//obj is actually a byte array with the same number of elements
```

I encounter the following error

```
[Ljava.lang.Byte; incompatible with [B
```

What causes this ?
Thanks in advance for your insight.

Comment: "Byte" is an object class that can contain a "byte".  "byte" is a "scalar" value, not an object class.  I'm guessing that "obj" is declared as "Byte[]", not "byte[]".

Comment: `Byte` and `byte` can be boxed/unboxed, but arrays of either type cannot be cast to one another. `byte[] != Byte[]`.

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to cast a `Byte[]` to a `byte[]`.  You can't do that in Java.

You have two choices:

- Change whatever is providing the `Byte[]` that is in `obj` to create a `byte[]` instead.
- Convert the `Byte[]` to a `byte[]`.  For example:

  ```
  Byte[] tmp (Byte[]) obj;
  byte[] a = new byte[obj.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      a[i] = tmp[i];
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks.  What's the type of Object? I mean when is a Object's type determined?  I have been using the same Object in other places, and it has no type at all(here, it's type seems to be Byte[]).

Comment: An object's type is determined when it is created and it never changes.  I repeat it *NEVER* changes.  If you have a `Byte[]` then it was created as a `Byte[]`.